# When parsing multiple feeds with SimplePie in PHP, the $feed variable always holds the first feed, even though the URL has changed

Tags: php, rss

I want to grab some data from a website where each page has its own feed. I therefore intend to grab all those feeds sequentially, like so:

```
$maxPages = 5;

for ($i = 1; $i <= $maxPages; $i++)
{
    // Create a new instance of the SimplePie object
    $feed = new SimplePie();
    $feed->set_feed_url('http://www.targetpage.org/forum?page=' . $i . '&foo=true');
    $feed->enable_cache(false);
    $feed->init();

    foreach($feed->get_items() as $item)
    {
        $md5 = md5($item->get_id());
        $title = $item->get_title();
        $href = $item->get_link();
        $content = $con->real_escape_string($item->get_content());

        //Insert the gathered data into the database
        $query = "INSERT INTO feed_items (md5, title, content, url) VALUES ('$md5', '$title', '$content', '$href')";
        mysqli_query($con, $query);
    }   
}
```

So while for every pass through the 'for' loop the URL changes, the stuff SimplePie returns is the same. Trying to destroy `$feed` in the end didn't help. What would I do to get a fresh feed every time?

Comment: Are you sure that the feed is actually different for the pages you are calling? If the call is not correct, it could actually be that the feeds are all the same because the default page is called